# How to remove bold from desktop font on OS X El Capitan

Tags: finder, macos, font, tweaks

I find the bold font on the desktop  takes up more room than necessary and doesn't make the text any easier for me to read. Is there a way I can remove this bold formatting independently from the rest of the system font?

OS X 10.11.1

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The only option available is changing font size (upon right clicking desktop), not the font or even its color. See this post [Change color of desktop font (Yosemite)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151341/change-color-of-desktop-font-yosemite)

[image]

[image]